# Clarification about the definition of Image of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be linear transformation and $V$ be finite dimension vector space.
I understand that $$IM (T)=\{v\in V|T(x)=v,x\in v\}$$ now my question is: if $IM (T)= IM (T^2)$
is that imply that $$T(x)=T^2(x)=v$$ or is it just imply that there is $x ,u \in V$ not neccessery equal s.t $$T(x)=T^2(u)=v$$

If the first option is true, I would like for an explnation for why is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $\operatorname{Image}(T) = \operatorname{Image}(T^2)$ is the second thing you wrote: for all $v \in V$, if there is $x \in V$ such that $T(x) = v$, then there is also $y \in V$ such that $T^2(y) = v$.

Notice that in order for the first thing you wrote to be true -- i.e., for all $v \in V$, if $T(x) = v$ then also $T^2(x) = v$ -- then we would actually have to have $T= T^2$.  It is definitely not true that just because $T$ and $T^2$ have the same image then they need to be equal: can you come up with an example?

Comment: Thank you. I understood now there is a big defference between $\operatorname{Image}(T) = \operatorname{Image}(T^2)$ and $T= T^2$ wich I used to think is the same meaning but with different notation.
The example I got up in mind is pretty simple $T(e_1)=0 , T(e_2)=e_3, T(e_3)=e_2$.
$e_i$ is the standard basis in R^3 . thanks for clarrifying that for me!

Answer (score 1):

Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}T\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&-x.\end{array}$$Then $\operatorname{Im}(T)=\operatorname{Im}(T^2)=\Bbb R$. However, if $x\in\Bbb R$ and $x\ne0$, then $T(x)=-x$, whereas$$T^2(x)=T\bigl(T(x)\bigr)=x\ne-x=T(x).$$On the other hand, if $v\in\operatorname{Im}(T)=\operatorname{Im}(T^2)$, then there are $x$ and $y$ in $V$ such that $T(x)=T^2(y)=v$.

Comment: That is good example, thank you!